# Symfony/Browser-Kit request files not visible in $_FILES but visible in injected HttpFoundation/Request

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have an issue where in tests I am sending a request via browser-kit with files and they are not visible in $_FILES but are visible in $request->files. I am using custom request validation class injected instead of HTTPFoundation/request into controller and in it I'm doing `Request::createFromGlobals();` which doeas not contain any files.

```
$uploadedFile = new UploadedFile(
            $uploadFilePath,
            $fileName
        );

        $this->kernelBrowser->request(
            "POST",
            "/upload",
            [],
            [
                "file" => $uploadedFile
            ]
        );
```

```
#[Route('upload', name: 'upload', methods: 'POST')]
    public function uploadFile(HttpFoundation Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        dd($_FILES, $request->files); //results in null and an UploadedFile object
    }
```